# How to erase the searchform, on the search results page, of indexed_search?

Tags: forms, search, typo3, typoscript, indexed

I tried to just erase the html markup from the indexed_search template file, this does work fine, until I found out that this causes a Javascript error where I can not use the numeric navigation. 
(*Page 1 Page 2 Page 3 Next >*).

So is there a typoscript command, or a other way, to erase the search form which is on the results page?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately when you empty the search form you won't be able to use the page browser at all. 
It is using the value from the search form and an offset (basically does a new search with your parameter)

Answer (score 0):

Idea for a workaround: How about hiding the standard search form (that contains the search term) with `display:none;` and adding a second, empty search form to the template?